# HTML Form JS Validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to validate my login form so that the field will have a min/max length before the values being posted to my PHP file.

**JavaScript:**

```
function loginValidation() {
    var user = document.login.username.value;
    var pass = document.login.password.value;

    if (user.length <= 6 || user.length > 20) {
        alert("Please make sure the username is between 7 and 20 characters.");
        return false;
    }

    if (pass.length <= 8 || pass.length > 50) {
        alert("Please make sure the password field is between 9 and 50 characters.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="login" onsubmit="loginValidation()" action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="username" class="lead para col-sm-4">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control transparent col-sm" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="lead para col-sm-4">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control col-sm" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

It seems that the code is ignoring the Function or that it just doesn't work (errors maybe?).

Other information that might be useful to know is that the JavaScript file with all my functions is external.

```
<script src="/JS/functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure if you're aware, but you can use `minlength` and `maxlength` attributes on HTML inputs to do this sort of thing for you instead of using JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/440/)**.

You are just missing the `return` in the function call in your `onsubmit`, should be like :

```
<form name="login" onsubmit="return loginValidation()" action="login.php" method="post">
_____________________________^^^^^^
```

It will be better to attach the event in your JS part :

```
document.querySelector('form[name="login"]').addEventListener("submit", loginValidation);
```

```js
function loginValidation() {
  var user = document.login.username.value;
  var pass = document.login.password.value;

  if (user.length <= 6 || user.length > 20) {
    alert("Please make sure the username is between 7 and 20 characters.");
    return false;
  }

  if (pass.length <= 8 || pass.length > 50) {
    alert("Please make sure the password field is between 9 and 50 characters.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="login" onsubmit="return loginValidation()" action="login.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="username" class="lead para col-sm-4">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control transparent col-sm" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="lead para col-sm-4">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control col-sm" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried with and without it, doesn't work either way. It just skips the JavaScript code as if it weren't there.

Comment: Should work, check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/440/

Comment: Ahh, yes it works only when the function is used within the HTML page (inline JavaScript) but when using the external file it doesn't work. :( Anyway to fix that? Thanks for the solution also.

Comment: What? No - I _never_ put my javascript inline in my html pages and my validations work fine ... but I also _never_ put event handlers inline like `onsubmit="..."`, I always _attach_ event handlers: `element.addEventListener("submit" ...);`

Comment: @StephenP note is correct, it will be better to attach the event in your JS, check my update..

Comment: @StephenP Is that just personal preference or does it work better?

Comment: @TheCodesee it is "best practice" ... [Separation of Concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/). You have some data _Model_, the HTML is the _View_, and the javascript is the _Controller_.  Keep your CSS separate too — design your HTML for what it _means_, then apply css to set how it _looks_. (although you could consider the html as the model and the css as the view)